# Im trying to setup IIS and get a 404.4 Error, don't have StaticFileModule

Tags: asp.net, iis

(Note: This is with IIS7)

When I go to http://localhost/MyApp, I get a 404.4 error, HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.  Going to http://localhost/MyApp/default.aspx it works.  I have searched and think I need to enable my StaticFileModule, but under Handler Mappings I don't have a StaticFileModule and don't know how/where to add it.  Can someone inform me if this is my problem and how to fix it?  Thanks!

```
Additional Error Details:

HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

Module: IIS Web Core

Notification: MapRequestHandler

Handler: Not yet determined

Error Code: 0x80070002
```

In IIS7 the default documents section lists default.aspx, which is what my default document is.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I initially has installed IIS from a Home Premium OS and had since upgraded to Business.  I installed all the new components I got from Business but the core iis installation was, I guess, still from Home, which was causing the errors.  A clean install fixed the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure you have a [default documents module installed](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-70-modules-overview/) (this will also have how to add a static file module, but I don't think that's your problem) ...

```
<globalModules> 
<add name="DefaultDocumentModule" image="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\defdoc.dll" />
...
```

Then, you can [add a default document](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/defaultDocument) ...

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="Default.aspx" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, I have just done those steps, added all the modules in the initial link you gave me as well as adding the default document in the web.config > configuration > system.webServer > defaultDocument section of my website.  I am still getting the same error.  I am about to add additional error details to my question.  If you have any other ideas they'd be greatly apprcaited!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Default Document setting on your virtual directory or website.

Here you can list default.html, default.aspx, index.html in whatever order.